# how to check that the device logging on my site is android or ios?

Tags: javascript, java, android, ios

I want to show smart app banner for both android and ios. Depending upon the device type , i will show the smart app banner.

Can it be done through Javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

you can recognize it via user agent ,
here is a example from w3c
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

iphone might be like

```
Browser Version: 5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1
```

android might be like

```
Browser Version: 5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Mobile Safari/537.36
```